# Error with Signals Post_Save and Pre_Save: created and self! how to fix?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

> It is necessary that after the addition of the series, the number of
>   the series is automatically added, if the administrator forgets to
>   add, in this way: we take the last created series, from there we take
>   the series number, and add to this the number of the series 1, and add
>   to our series! But constantly vylazyut such errors as:

1) lacks the

> argument "self", add it (although why it is there at all, it is not
>   known) and still does not work!

## this is my models and SIGNALS

```
class Series(models.Model):
    id                                          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rus_name                                    = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    eng_name                                    = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    slug                                        = models.SlugField(unique=False) 
    serial_of_this_series                       = models.ForeignKey(Serial, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    season_of_this_series                       = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    number_of_series                            = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    description                                 = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=True, default=None)
    size_of_torent_file                         = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_360p     = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_720p     = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    link_for_dowloand_serie_in_quality_1080p    = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)      
    rating                                      = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)  
    is_active                                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp_rus                               = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    timestamp_eng                               = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    time_of_series                              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=42)



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series:post_of_serie', kwargs=
                      {'serial_slug': self.serial_of_this_series.slug,
                       'season_slug': self.season_of_this_series.slug,
                       'series_slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s | %s" % (self.rus_name, self.number_of_series)


    class Meta:
        ordering                                = ["-timestamp_rus"]
        verbose_name                            = 'Series'
        verbose_name_plural                     = 'Series'


def series_change_number(sender, **kwargs):
    ser                                         = Series.objects.last()
    change                                      = ser.number_of_series
    number                                      = int(change) + 1
    series                                      = Series
    series.number_of_series                     = number
    series.save(force_update=True)

pre_save.connect(series_change_number, sender=Series)
```

Comment: Remove "created" param in your series_change_number function.

Comment: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: do you want to create a new Series object in your function or update the same in-place?

Comment: I need to update, namely, to update the series number, and that was all right, we take the number of the series from the previous one created, and add 1 to our model, thus, when saving the administrator, there will be a corresponding serial number!

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok do this:

```
def series_change_number(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ser = Series.objects.last()
    change = ser.number_of_series
    number = int(change) + 1
    instance.number_of_series = number

pre_save.connect(series_change_number, sender=Series)
```

provided you are looking to update the new model object.

Comment: new error with your answer "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: this line is again calling up the pre_save signal hence maximum depth issue

Comment: You are a genius, thank you very much) such another question, if you allow) how to take the last created, that is, the one that stands above all, and then it takes the most 1 created, it turns out the last, I tried to try using the "first ()" method but not Works, he always takes 1 created and adds to it 1 and it is necessary that he took the last created series, and took from there the number of the series! Thank you very much)

Comment: Your next question is a bit confusing. could you elaborate more?

Comment: Let's say there are 2 entries in the admin panel, these are 2 series, and when he adds it, he takes 1 series, that is, the most created one, that is, the old one, and the number to the next one will not be correct, but it is necessary that he take the last created, that is not 1 series, that is, a series of 1, the last added

Answer (score 0):

Please don't line up your code like that; it makes it very hard to read.

Your problem is here (removing the spaces):

```
series = Series
```

That just makes `series` another name for the Series class. You don't ever instantiate it; to do so you need to actually call it.

```
series = Series()
```

... assuming that is actually what you want to do; it's not clear from your code.

Comment: ok, how to do this?Can you help the newcomer?                                                         and i get new error @maximum recursion depth exceeded@ with this "series=Series()"

Comment: As I said, you need to explain exactly what you are trying to do. This code is being called when a new Series is created. Are you trying to update the number on the instance that is causing the signal to be called?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think what he is looking for is to update the number_of_series of the currently saving database model wrt last saved objects.